# Why do both the abstract class and interface exist in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

Why do both the abstract class and interface exist in C# if we can achieve the interface feature by making all the members in the class as abstract.

Is it because:

1. Interface exists to have multiple inheritance
2. It makes sense to have interface because object's CAN-DO feature should be placed in an interface rather base abstract class.

Please clarify

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Well, an abstract class can specify *some* implemetation, but usually not all of it. (Having said which, it's perfectly possible to provide an abstract class with no abstract members, but plenty of virtual ones which with "no-op" implementations). An interface provides *no* implementation, merely a contract.

You could certainly argue that if multiple inheritance of classes were permitted, interfaces would be largely pointless.

Personally I don't get hung up on the whole "is-a" vs "can-do" distinction for inheritance. It never gives me as good an intuition about what to do as just playing around with different ideas and seeing which ones feel the most flexible. (Then again, I'm very much a "favour composition over inheritance" guy...)

EDIT: Just as the most convenient way of rebutting lbushkin's third point in his comment... you can override an abstract method with a non-virtual one (in terms of not being able to override it further) by sealing it:

```
public abstract class AbstractBase
{
    public abstract void Foo();
}

public class Derived : AbstractBase
{
    public sealed override void Foo() {}
}
```

Classes deriving from `Derived` cannot override `Foo` any further.

I'm not in any way suggesting I want multiple inheritance of implementation - but if we *did* have it (along with its complexity) then an abstract class which *just* contained abstract methods would accomplish *almost* everything that an interface does. (There's the matter of explicit interface implementation, but that's all I can think of at the moment.)

Comment: "favour composition over inheritance". Well there are scenarios where the opposite is more desirable, like any kind of GUI library, where inheritance is a blessing. IMHO a well though out design based on (correct) inheritance is more useful than a design based on composition if there are sufficient hierarchies. But..inheritance is harder than composition in any case (is that a flaw of OOP, as we use it today?)

Comment: "if multiple inheritance of classes were permitted, interfaces would be largely pointless". I would disagree with that assertion. First, interfaces provide a level of decoupling that even purely abstract base classes full of virtual no-op methods can't provide. They help separate the contractual obligations of a type from the inevitable implementation-centric concerns. Second, since interfaces have no data members, they avoid the issue of diamond inheritance of data. Third, C# allows methods that implement an interface to be non-virtual (which can be useful) - abstract classes do not.

Comment: Sorry Jon gotta disagree with you on the multiple inheritance. As someone who's spent a lot of his life in C++, trust me, it's horrible. Most developers in C++ now use multiple inheritence in pretty much the same way as c#/java i.e one main base class plus everything else as 'mix-ins'

Comment: @LBushkin: Point 1: if you have an abstract base class with purely virtual methods, how is that coupling you more than an interface? Point 2: Yes, I'm not saying multiple inheritance doesn't have its downsides, nor was I calling for it... but you can write an abstract class with purely virtual methods and *no* fields. Point 3: You can seal the virtual methods of base classes: I'll edit my post to show that.

Answer (score 17):

It's not a trivial question, it's a very good question and one I always ask any candidates I interview.
In a nutshell - an abstract base class defines a type hierarchy whereas an interface defines a contract.

You can see it as *is a* vs *implements a*.
i.e
`Account` could be an abstract base account because you could have a `CheckingAccount`, a `SavingsAccount`, etc all which derive from the abstract base class `Account`. Abstract base classes may also contain non abstract methods, properties and fields just like any normal class. However interfaces **only** contain abstract methods and properties that **must** be implemented.

c# let's you derive from one base class only - single inheritance just like java.  However you can implement as many interfaces as you like - this is because an interface is just a contract which your class promises to implement.

So if I had a class `SourceFile` then my class could choose to implement `ISourceControl` which says 'I faithfully promise to implement the methods and properties that `ISourceControl` requires'

This is a big area and probably worthy of a better post than the one I've given however I'm short on time but I hope that helps!

Answer (score 8):

They both exist because they are both very different things.  Abstract classes permit implementation and interfaces do not.  An interface is very handy as it allows me to to say something about the type I am building (it is serializable, it is edible, etc.) but it does not allow me to define *any* implementation for the members I define.

An abstract class is more powerful that an interface in the sense that it allows me to create an inheritance interface via abstract and virtual members but also provide some sort of default or base implementation if I so choose.  As Spiderman knows, however, with that great power comes great responsibility as an abstract class is more architecturally brittle.

**Side Note:** *Something interesting to note is that Vance Morrrison (of the CLR team) has speculated about adding default method implementations to interfaces in a future version of the CLR.   This would greatly blur the distinction between an interface and an abstract class.  See [this video](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Going+Deep/Vance-Morrison-CLR-Through-the-Years/) for details.*

Answer (score 2):

One important reason both mechanisms exist because c#.NET only allows single inheritance, not multiple inheritance like C++.  The class inheritance allows you to inherit implementation from only one place; everything else must be accomplished by implementing interfaces.

For example, let's suppose I create a class, like Car and I subclass into three subclasses, RearWheelDrive, FrontWheelDrive, and AllWheelDrive.  Now I decide that I need to cut my classes along a different "axis," like those with push-button starters and those without.  I want all pushbutton start cars to have a "PushStartButton()" method and non-pushbutton cars to have a "TurnKey()" method and I want to be able to treat Car objects (with regard to starting them) irrespective of which subclass they are.  I can define interfaces that my classes can implement, such as IPushButtonStart and IKeyedIgnition, so I have a common way to deal with my objects that differ in a way that is independent of the single base class from which each derives.

Answer (score 1):

You gave a good answer already. I think your second answer is the real reason. If I wanted to make an object Compareable I shouldn't have to derive from a Comparable base class. if you think of all the interfaces think of all the permutations you'd beed to handle the basic interfaces like IComparable.

Interfaces let us define a contract around the publicly exposed behavior an object provides. Abstract classes let you define both behavior and implementation, which is a very different thing.

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces exist to provide a class without any implementation whatsoever, so that .NET can provide support for safe and functional multiple inheritance in a managed environment.

Answer (score 0):

An Interface defines a contract that an implementing class must fulfil; it is a way of stating that "this does that".  An Abstract Class is a partial implementation of a class which is by definition incomplete, and which needs a derviation to be completed.  They're very different things.

Comment: The implementation of the abstract class may actually be complete already - there's no requirement that it have any abstract members. It's rarely useful to derive from an abstract class and not override anything, but it's perfectly legal.

Comment: Ah, good point; still, the definition of "abstract class" means that it cannot be instantiated, so there must be a derivation to instatiate it; I still consider that to be "incomplete" because you cannot use it by itself.  Still, your point is very relevant and well taken.

Answer (score 0):

An `abstract` `class` can have an implementation while an `interface` just allows you to create a contract that implementers have to follow. With abstract classes you can provide a common **behavior** to their sub classes witch you can't with interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

They serve two distinctly different purposes.

Abstract classes provide a way to have a an object inherit from a defined contract, as well as allowing behavior to be specified in the base class.  This, from a theoretical standpoint, provides an **IS-A** relationship, in that the concrete class IS-A specific type of the base class.

Interfaces allow classes to define a (or more than one) contract which they will fulfill.  They allow for a **ACTS-AS** or "can be used as an" type of relationship, as opposed to direct inheritance.  This is why, typically, interfaces will use an adjective as they're name (IDisposable) instead of a noun.

Answer (score 0):

An interface is used for what a class can do, but it is also used to hide some of things that a class can do.

For example the `IEnumerable<T>` interface describes that a class can iterate through it's members, but it's also limits the access to this single ability. A `List<T>` can also access the items by index, but when you access it through the `IEnumerable<T>` interface, you only know about it's ability to iterate the members.

If a method accepts the `IEnumerable<T>` interface as a parameter, that means that it's only interrested in the ability to iterate through the members. You can use several different classes with this ability (like a `List<T>` or an array `T[]`) without the need for one method for each class.

Not only can a method accept several different classes that implement an interface, you can create new classes that implement the interface and the method will happily accept those too.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is simple - if your class(YourClass) is already deriving from a parent class(SomeParentClass) and at the same time you want your class(YourClass) to have a new behavior that is defined in some abstract class(SomeAbstractClass), you can't do that by simply deriving from that abstract class(SomeAbstractClass), C# doesn't allow multiple inheritance.
However if your new behavior was instead defined in an interface (IYourInterface), you could easily derive from the interface(IYourInterface) along with parent class(SomeParentClass).

Consider having a class **Fruit** that is derived by two children(**Apple** & **Banana**) as shown below:

```
class Fruit
{
    public virtual string GetColor()
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
}

class Apple : Fruit
{
    public override string GetColor()
    {
        return "Red";
    }
}

class Banana : Fruit
{
    public override string GetColor()
    {
        return "Yellow";
    }
}
```

We have an existing interface **ICloneable** in **C#**. This interface has a single method as shown below, a class that implements this interface guarantees that it can be cloned:

```
public interface ICloneable
{
    object Clone();
}
```

Now if I want to make my **Apple** class(not **Banana** class) clonable, I can simpley implement **ICloneable** like this:

```
 class Apple : Fruit , ICloneable
{
    public object Clone()
    {
        // add your code here
    }

    public override string GetColor()
    {
        return "Red";
    }
}
```

Now considering your argument of pure abstract class, if **C#** had a pure abstract class say **Clonable** instead of interface **IClonable** like this:

```
abstract class Clonable
{
    public abstract object Clone();
}
```

Could you now make your **Apple** class clonable by inheriting the abstract **Clonable** instead of **IClonable**? like this:

```
// Error: Class 'Apple' cannot have multiple base classes: 'Fruit' & 'Clonable'
class Apple : Fruit, Clonable
{
    public object Clone()
    {
        // add your code here
    }

    public override string GetColor()
    {
        return "Red";
    }
}
```

No, you can't, because a class cannot derive from multiple classes.