# Interface implementation Differences

Tags: vb.net

What is the difference of using interfaces like ...

I have an interface

```
Public Interface IProDataSource

    Function read() As Integer

End Interface
```

Then a class

```
Public Class DataSource : Implements IProDataSource

     Function read() As Integer Implements IProDataSource.read

         some code...

     End Function

End Class
```

Then I use this the next way ... but what is the difference? ...  both approaches are working ...

```
Dim obj As IProDataSource = New DataSource
obj.read()
```

vs

```
Dim datas as new Datasource
datas.read()
```

The only difference I have notice is that if the method is declare private it will be visible using the first approach only.

Thanks for any comments !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `obj` is a `DataSource`, you cannot get to the non-Interface methods of the DataSource through a variable declared as the interface. Otherwise, in your example, there is really no difference.

Notice the "is a".

`IList` is a good interface to check out. Many objects take or use `IList` as method parameters. (To see all the classes that implement `IList`, open the "Object Browser", browse to `IList` and expand "Derived Types".) For example, if I was implementing a Windows.Forms control, instead of forcing you to pass a list as an `Array`, `List`, `Collection`, or some other object, I could specify `IList` and any class that implements that interface can be used by the control.

A practical example, the `DataSource` property of a `ComboBox` accepts any object that implements the `System.Collections.IList` interface, such as a `System.Data.DataSet` or an `System.Array`.

> **Interfaces Overview**
>
> Interfaces, like classes, define a set
>   of properties, methods, and events.
>   But unlike classes, interfaces do not
>   provide implementation. They are
>   implemented by classes, and defined as
>   separate entities from classes.
>
> An interface represents a contract, in
>   that a class that implements an
>   interface must implement every aspect
>   of that interface exactly as it is
>   defined.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3et34z3(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

At the moment is seems like using the interface is a waste of effort...

But what happens if tomorrow you, or omebody else, decides to write an XMLDatasource, or a CSVDatasource, or an InternetDataSource.

If you implement your applicatino using the first way ( Dim obj as IProDataSource) then you don't need to care what *kind* of datasource is being used.  As long as whaterver DataSource implements the interface, your program will work with it.

IF you use the second method (Dim datas as new DataSource) then when I try to use my SuperFancyDataSource with your program, you'll have to go through your whole program and change all of the  New DataSources to  New SuperFanceDataSource.

Answer (score 0):

See this question from a friend of mine:

[Why is an interface or an abstract class useful? (or for what?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845601/why-is-an-interface-or-an-abstract-class-useful-or-for-what)