# How to call an interface in C#

Tags: c#, .net, oop, interface

```
interface ISample
{
    int fncAdd();
}

class ibaseclass
{
    public int intF = 0, intS = 0;
    int Add()
    {
        return intF + intS;
    }
}
class iChild : ibaseclass, ISample
{
    int fncAdd()
    {
        int intTot = 0;
        ibaseclass obj = new ibaseclass();
        intTot = obj.intF;
        return intTot;
    }
}
```

I want to call `ISample` in `static void Main(string[] args)` but I dont know how to do that. Could you please tell me how?

Comment: According to your question, I really don't think you have grasped the purpose of an interface.

Comment: As mentioned above, I don't think you know what interfaces are. See this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87d83y5b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 10):

An interface cannot be instantiated by itself. You can't just *call* an interface. You need to *instantiate* a class that actually *implements* the interface.

Interfaces don't and can't do anything by themselves.

For example:

```
ISample instance = new iChild(); // iChild implements ISample
instance.fncAdd();
```

The following questions provide more detailed answers about this:

- [Why is an interface or an abstract class useful? (or for what?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845601/why-is-an-interface-or-an-abstract-class-useful-or-for-what)
- [Interface vs Abstract Class (general OO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761194/interface-vs-abstract-class-general-oo)

Answer (score 2):

You can't "call" interface or create instance of it.

What you **can** do is have your class *implement* the interface then use its method `fncAdd`.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean?:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ISample child = new iChild();
    child.fncAdd();
}
```

Although, as stated by others the code doesn't seem like it's using inheritance correctly.